# Is there a way I can gnu screen a tty device in C++/Python on MacOS?

Tags: python, c++, linux, linux-device-driver, tty

I want to send data out of my C++ program into a tty port. However, I am experiencing significant problems regarding using system(echo > tty) and ofstream dev(tty).

I found that the only thing that works is screen tty.device from the command line, so is it possible for me to open up my device using screen from c++ and then send data to it from my c++ program?

Python is fine too if a solution exists.

Comment: Is there an obvious way to do this hence the downvotes?

Comment: Sorry, don't know much about MacOS.  If you are interested, I could describe (with code snippets) how I do this on Ubuntu, you'd recognize the C++,  and might get some clues on questions to ask ( for how do this on MacOS).

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042413/does-bidirectional-popen-work-on-mac-os-x-in-c) it might help

Comment: @2785528 Yeah if you have any code snippets that would be great!

Comment: @yashC Thanks a lot! That might be what I'm looking for. However, I'm doing this:     FILE *pout;
    pout = popen("screen tty.MobileRobot-RNI-SPP", "w");
    fprintf(pout,"hello");

Comment: @yashC Then it's giving me a "Must be connected to a terminal" message. Why's that?